# parse_url() with colons and numbers

Tags: php

Since I don't have access to mod rewrite I am using this to parse my URL.

```
$path = explode("/", parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
```

So when my URL is `/page/action/1` it works nicely. I get this:

```
[0] => [1] => page [2] => action [3] => 1
```

However when I have something like: `/page/action/simple:1` it breaks. It returns nothing.

Does anyone know why this happens what I can do to fix it?

Comment: It seems it is an open issue https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71646

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So someone posted about `urlencode()` but then deleted their answer. I toyed around with it and found this solution. It isn't the greatest by any stretch but it worked for me.

I'd still be interested in hearing from anyone if they have any better alternatives. But here is what I changed.

```
$path = explode(urlencode("/"), parse_url(urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), PHP_URL_PATH));
foreach($path as &$item) $item = urldecode($item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path = explode("/", $url);
var_dump($path);
```

If `$url = /page/action/simple:1`
The output should be `[0] => [1] => page [2] => action [3] => simple:1`